# scheduled job on cronr not running, log reads '/bin/sh: Rscript: command not found'

Tags: r, bash, macos

I am using [cronr](https://github.com/bnosac/cronR) add in with RStudio (on Mac OSX 10.11.6 El Capitain) to schedule my script fetch_n_write.R.

If I select 'Once' from the `Schedule` options in the pop up, the script is run immediately and the file it generates is outputted. Success!

If I try to schedule the job to run daily in 2 minutes, the log shows it running the code but then ends with '/bin/sh: Rscript: command not found' and the file does not get written. No Success.

I am guessing after some searching that this has to do something with permissions. It was [suggested](https://github.com/andrewheiss/SublimeKnitr/issues/32)that R might need to be reinstalled, but `which R` results in
`/usr/local/bin/R` and `which Rscript`results in 
`/usr/local/bin/Rscript` which I think means I should not have to reinstall R?

Comment: What is the command you are using in cron?

Comment: I'm not actually using a command in cron, directly so I dont know. but I believe the cronr addin is using the r function cron_add which says it "generates a cron job". if I do `crontab -e` in a terminal i do see my job.

Comment: So what do you see when you do `crontab -e` or `crontab -l` ?

Comment: ## cronR job
## id:   job_41128dd1c24804f704afd9a928f1ff4d
## tags: 
## desc: this is a test
19 21 * * * Rscript /Users/sco_lo_code/Data_Science/Stopbot/fetch_n_write.R  >> /Users/sco_lo_code/Data_Science/Stopbot/fetch_n_write.log 2>&1

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem is in the `cron` command, and the job fails because the absolute path is not used for  the actual command portion (returning the error `'/bin/sh: Rscript: command not found'`):

```
19 21 * * * Rscript /Users/ ...
```

`cron` does not know where to find `Rscript`, so you must specify:

```
19 21 * * * /usr/local/bin/Rscript /Users/ ...
```

Comment: So, I typed `env EDITOR=nano crontab -e` which brought up my cron job. I updated the path as you described and changed the time two mins ahead, then pressed `ctrl o`, saved the file, then `ctrl x`. It doesn't seem to work, however, as the log appears to have the same message. I do `crontab -l` and get

## cronR job
## id:   job_41128dd1c24804f704afd9a928f1ff4d
## tags: 
## desc: this is a test
05 22 * * * /usr/local/bin/Rscript/Users/sco_lo_code/Data_Science/SuicideStopbot/fetch_n_write.R  >>/usr/local/bin/Rscript/Users/sco_lo_code/Data_Science/SuicideStopbot/fetch_n_write.log 2>&1

Comment: You need a space between `/usr/local/bin/Rscript` and `/Users/...` as shown in my answer.

Comment: ok, my bad - i updated the space. its still not working. log still shows '/bin/sh: Rscript: command not found'

Comment: Show the updated error message, also when you do `Rscript` from the command-line does it work?

Comment: `Rscript` returns 'Usage: /path/to/Rscript [--options] [-e expr [-e expr2 ...] | file] [args] ... '

Comment: After updating my version of R, I entered my cron job exactly as you suggested using `crontab -e` and it works now. appreciate the help very much